# Unable to open file and read from it

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, istream

I call the code with "temperatures.txt" which is a file with the following format:

-9.3    -15.1

-9.0    -14.1

..

..

Also temps is a struct with: int max,min;  // temperatures
The final vector should be used to fill two open_polylines and construct a graph with max and min temperatures, but it produces an empty window --> thus it must be that the vector to be returned (vec) is empty

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Temps& t){
    //assume format (max----min)
    string c1="    ";
    Temps tt;

    is >> t.max >> t.min;
    //return is;}
    t=tt;
    return is;
}

vector<Temps> readTemp(string fileName){
    ifstream temp_file{fileName};
    Temps t;
    vector<Temps> vec;
    if(!temp_file){
        error("Can't open ", fileName);
    }
    
    while(temp_file>>t){
        cout<<t.max << t.min;
        vec.push_back(t);
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `is >> t.max >> t.min;` reads the data into `t` but you then do `t = tt` ?

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Temps& t){
    //assume format (max----min)
    string c1="    ";
    Temps tt;

    is >> t.max >> t.min;
    //return is;}
    t=tt;
    return is;
}
```

You read the temperatures into `t` but then you overwrite them with `tt`. Just do it like this, there's no need for `tt` (or `c1`).

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Temps& t){
    //assume format (max----min)
    return is >> t.max >> t.min;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but it still refuses to open the "temperatures.txt" file. Could it have something to do with the 4 "spaces" between max and min temperature?

Comment: @MariElise No, because `operator>>` skips spaces. So if you've fixed `operator>>` the bug is probably somewhere after you've called `readTemp`. Somewhere in the code you didn't post in other words. This is why it's best to post complete programs.

Comment: @MariElise When you say it refuses to open "temperatures.txt" do you mean that you see the `error("Can't open ", fileName);` message? If so then it's simply that your temparatures.txt file isn't where the program is expecting to find it.